Why is this variable used in Laravel function
I am working on this beginner Laravel tutorial. In this example, why is the variable $incomingFields required?
class userController extends Controller
{
public function register(Request $Request) {
  $incomingFields = $Request->validate({
     'name' => 'required',
     'email' ='required',
     'password' => 'required'
  ]);
  return 'Hello from our controller';
  }
}

Link to tutorial
I removed the variable and it works.

It isn't; you're not using it, so your code could simply be $request->validate(...); return ...;. Sidenote, variables are camelCase, so $Request should be $request.

There's actually a lot of typos here that would cause the code to not work. $Request is against the recommended formatting, but wouldn't break the code.

You're not using $incomingFields so you don't need it. But it returns an array that you can use, if you wanted.

I see later in the tutorial that the variable is used to create a model. Thanks.

$incomingFields isn't required, but the use of it in this scenario would be so that the inputs sent through via the request are checked against the validation rules set elsewhere in the code:
Link to validation section of Laravel docs
the response from the validate function would be stored in $incomingFields, allowing for custom handling.
